# Python OpenCV script run over SSH (X Error of failed request: BadRequest)

Tags: python, opencv, ssh, xorg

I need to execute python script with OpenCV over ssh. The problem is that I get X error when I call any opencv function.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv 

a = np.zeros((200, 100), dtype=np.uint8)
b = cv.resize(a, (100, 50)) # got error here
```

The error is not an exception or assertion, it just stops program and prints:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (DRI2)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  1 (DRI2Connect)
  Serial number of failed request:  11
  Current serial number in output stream:  11
```

I understand that opencv function uses somehow X's DRI. (Direct Rendering Infrastructure) So I need to probably somehow use remote pc X and not using ssh X11 forwarding.

**Question:**
Does anybody know how to force opencv running in ssh session to use remote X or any other way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, make sure you have **disabled** X11forwarding on your localhost.

That means do not use any of `-X -Y`  options and make sure X11 forwarding is not enabled in configuration.

```
~/.ssh/config 
/etc/ssh/ssh_config)

ForwardX11 no
```